# Is it possible to render .doc file in qt on linux?

Tags: linux, qt, ms-office

All I need is to show `.doc` files in qt application on Linux. No need edit/save or something else.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. But the file reading, parsing, and displaying would really be carried out by the underlying language, not Qt. So, if you think about it, C++ and Python and whatever else is quite capable of parsing and displaying what is essentially a text file (or for .dox an XML file).

The implementation details of how to go about that are quite another matter. You have to contend with a huge portion of the file that is merely there to render the file's styling, etc.